# android balloon overlay in image

Tags: android, imageview, overlay, balloon

I need to create a balloon overlay from where a user click presses on the imageview. 
it's look like this.
http://www.modality.com/images/appimages/130/screens/645/large.png

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can modify some of this code? [Github baloontips project](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Other option is to check where the user has tapped (onTouchListener) and then inflate your own custom baloon layout.